# Error running Selenium automatically from Nightwatch.js with Firefox

Tags: node.js, windows, selenium, nightwatch.js, geckodriver

I want to start Selenium Server automatically when I run a nightwatch.js test case. I changed the selenium settings on nightwatch.json to:

```
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./selenium/selenium391.jar",
    "log_path" : "C:/Projects/reports",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./selenium/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "./selenium/IEDriverServer.exe",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "./selenium/geckodriver.exe"
    }
  },
```

This configuration works when I use Chrome as browser. However I got an error when I run it using Firefox:

```
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session (312ms) { value:
   { message: 'Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService\nBuild info: ver
sion: \'3.9.1\', revision: \'63f7b50\', time: \'2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z\'\nSyst
em info: host: \'IBS-PC192\', ip: \'192.168.1.115\', os.name: \'Windows 7\', os.
arch: \'x86\', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'1.8.0_112\'\nDriver info: dr
iver.version: unknown',
     error: 'session not created' },
  status: 33 }
```

If I run the Selenium Server manually, the nightwatch test works on Firefox. How do I resolve this?

**nightwatch.json file:** for Firefox

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "C:/Projects/global/globals.js",
  "live_output" : false,
  "parallel_process_delay" : 10,
  "disable_colors": false,
  "test_workers" : false,

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./selenium/selenium391.jar",
    "log_path" : "C:/Projects/reports",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./selenium/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "./selenium/IEDriverServer.exe",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "./selenium/geckodriver.exe"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port" : 4444,
      "silent" : true,
      "disable_colors": false,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
    },
```

**The content of selenium-debug.log**

```
14:24:00.791 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50'
14:24:00.791 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-02-16 14:24:00.853:INFO::main: Logging initialized @280ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-02-16 14:24:00.962:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.7.v20170914, build timestamp: 2017-11-21T22:27:37+01:00, git hash: 82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8
2018-02-16 14:24:00.978:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5ed7a6{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2018-02-16 14:24:00.978:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5ed7a6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2018-02-16 14:24:01.352:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@18f65a4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2018-02-16 14:24:01.352:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @782ms
14:24:01.352 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
2018-02-16 14:24:01.540:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp17048053-10: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-132ec19: Initialising WebDriverServlet
14:24:01.618 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@1e1a802
14:24:01.618 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
14:24:01.680 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: firefox, javascriptEnabled: true, name: Google Wiki}
14:24:01.680 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: firefox, javascriptEnabled: true, name: Google Wiki} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing does gives us some hint about whats going wrong as follows :

```
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session (312ms) { value: { message: 'Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.9.1\', revision: \'63f7b50\', time: \'2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'IBS-PC192\', ip: \'192.168.1.115\', os.name: \'Windows 7\', os.arch: \'x86\', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'1.8.0_112\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown', error: 'session not created' }, status: 33 }
```

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) [***Response 500***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

The main reason is the **binaries** you are using are **incompatible** as :

- *Selenium Client* version is as **selenium391.jar** released **'2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'**
- But the *JDK* version is as **java.version: '1.8.0_112** which is pretty **ancient**.

### Solution

A quick solution would be to :

- Update the *JDK* version to recent levels i.e. [***Java SE Development Kit 8u161***](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Run [**`CCleaner`**](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off the OS chores before and after executing your *Test Suite*

---

### Update

As you mentioned in your comment that you still got the same error you need to change the following line :

```
"webdriver.firefox.profile" : "./selenium/geckodriver.exe"
```

To :

```
"webdriver.gecko.driver" : "./selenium/geckodriver.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I still got the same error even though I already updated my JDK and ran CCleaner. I have currently no problem with Chrome and IE.

Comment: minor version shouldn't matter as long as you are on JDK 8

Comment: @User2018 Added an update to my answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm afraid I won't be able to post the result until Monday, but I will let you know as soon as possible! @Corey Goldberg good to know. Thanks for the Info!

Comment: @DebanjanB It works! I guess Firefox Driver (`webdriver.firefox.profile`) does not work anymore for Firefox 47+ ([link](https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/solving-firefox-47-selenium-webdriver-problem-1c1e455c2189)) and replaced with gecko driver for Firefox 47+. Right?